# Spark Dataframes: appending list in a new column(python)

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I am having the following dataframe(values inside array are strings):

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                col1|                col2|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|    [value1, value2]|     [value3,value4]|
|            [value5]|            [value6]|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

How can I create an new column with a new array including all the values of both

```
+--------------------+--------------------+------------------------------+
|                col1|                col2|                          new |
+--------------------+--------------------+------------------------------+
|    [value1, value2]|     [value3,value4]|[value1, value2,value3,value4]|
|            [value5]|            [value6]|               [value5,value6]|
+--------------------+--------------------+------------------------------+
```

I tried the following:

```
def add_function(col1,col2):
    return col1+col2

udf_add = udf(add_function,ArrayType(StringType()))
dftrial.withColumn("new",udf_add("col1","col2")).show(2)
```

It does do the task as desired. But I dont understand why when I modify the `add_function` to:

```
def add_function(col1,col2):
     return col1.extend(col2)
```

It returns `null` value. Why?

And my main question: Is there another way to implement this task, Any already implemented function? I found `concat` but it seems that it works only for strings.

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't it? Using Python type hints `list.extend` is:

```
list.extend(iterable) -> None
```

So you get exactly what is returned from `extend`. If you wanted to return modify collection you should actually return `col1` but please don't because there is actually a worse part here.

You should **never** modify data in place when working with Spark. While in this particular scenario you're safe it can have unpredictable consequences. You can find possible example in my answer to [Will there be any scenario, where Spark RDD's fail to satisfy immutability.?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32426067/1560062). While PySpark is relatively insulated from behaviors like this it is only an implementation detail and not something you can depend on in general.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you clarify what I should never do? Because i didnt understand it exactly and it seems to be an important information that I am missing.

Comment: `list.extend` modifies (mutates) existing `list`. Don't do this with your data. Always return a new object unless it is explicitly allowed to do otherwise (see `RDD.fold`, `RDD.aggregate`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @zero323. I just wanted to add the transformation that would be necessary to get the solution in a new dataframe.

```
  val updatedDataframe = initialDataframe.map {
    case Row(col1: Seq[String], col2: Seq[String]) => (col1, col2, col1.union(col2))
  }.toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")
```